# soapclient no puede abrir https - php

Tags: php, soap, soapui

llevo dias tratando de dar solucion a este problema lo vi varias veces en consultas y no dan solucion.
este es el mensaje de error y etse el codigo

> Warning:  SoapClient::SoapClient() [soapclient.soapclient]: I/O
>   warning : failed to load external entity
>   "https://ws5.pide.gob.pe/services/ReniecConsultaDni?WSDL" in
>   C:\AppServ\www\wsdl\index.php on line 4

mi codigo es

```
 $client = new SoapClient('https://ws5.pide.gob.pe/services/ReniecConsultaDni?WSDL');
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

tambien hice la prueba con nusoap

```
    require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
$wsdl="https://ws5.pide.gob.pe/services/ReniecConsultaDni?wsdl";
$client=new nusoap_client($wsdl, true);
$param=array('nuDniConsulta'=>'xxx','nuDniUsuario'=>'xxx','nuRucUsuario'=>'20xxx','password'=>'xxx');
$dni = $client->call('consultar',$param);
header("Content-Type:text/html");
// hacemos la impresion de informacion
print_r ($dni);

resultado

    Array
(
    [faultcode] => ns0:Server
    [faultstring] => HV000116: The object to be validated must not be null.
)
```

si alguien podria orientarme al web service me concto normal con soapui y con visual studio pero con php es mi inconveniente.

Comment: A mi esa url a la que intentas acceder me da error, tanto accediendo desde un navegador como haciéndole un ping al dominio a secas. Seguro que esa url es correcta?

Comment: si, es la correcta. son los permisos solo se podra acceder desde mi ip de otra no. pero el problema persiste